# Trying to convert a serial date from excel into a date in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a list of serial numbers which I extracted from excel into proper dates in python using the code below. I am using a for loop to iterate over the array or list.

```
for i in excel_date_arr:
    dt = datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + excel_date_arr[i] - 2)
    tt = dt.timetuple()
    new_dates = new_dates.append(tt)
```

However, I keep getting errors. Below is the error that appears for the code above. I am totally new to python.

---

> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 1 for i in excel_date_arr:
> ----> 2     dt = datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + excel_date_arr[i] - 2)
> 3     tt = dt.timetuple()
> 4     new_dates = new_dates.append(tt)

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: What is the format of the excel data you want to convert into a time value?